# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I've been getting this notice on my Chrome dev tools with each http request. I have never subscribed to any superfish.com services.

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=diigo&userId=153ec8d45ab00bb0221c814e5d659bee". contentscript.js:398
```

Does anybody know the origin of this and how I can stop it?

Comment: The same on Ubuntu.

Comment: This question was [cross-posted and answered on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288769/resource-interpreted-as-script-but-transferred-with-mime-type-text-html-superfis).

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the [Better History Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history-manager/gnlpmgpphnmjfnfdfgfagnaaephafllc) extension?
The error disappeared when I was disabled it.